# -bash: last_pipe_status: bad array subscript

Tags: bash, shell

Every time I execute a command I get this error in the shell. I have no idea where it is coming from, but I imagine it is something trivial. I have scoured the internet but could not find anything specific to this problem.

This is error I am getting :

`-bash: last_pipe_status: bad array subscript`

Comment: I bet this is your prompt trying to check the exit status of the last command. What is the value of your `PS1` prompt variable, and what do you see if you run any command with `set -x`?

Comment: It has must have to do with Powerline. Ever since I installed it, my shell has been throwing that error. http://imgur.com/a/Uozcx

Comment: I fear the answer is "you messed up the Powerline install" then.

Comment: I get this and I've just attempted to install powerline, so perhaps something has changed recently

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a configuration issue. Check the version of bash installed on the system.

`bash -version`

Powerline requires the latest version of bash.

After I updated the bash to the latest version the error vanished.
I use macOS High Sierra and the default terminal (not iTerm2).

To update bash I did `brew install bash` and to get the new bash to work with terminal had to change the Preferences from Terminal menu.

`Terminal -> Preferences...`

In the `General` tab for `Shell opens with:` select `Command (complete path)` and specify the new bash location.

In my case it was `/usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.4.19/bin/bash`

References:

https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1788
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx